# Best way to store JSON files

Tags: ios, json

I'm completing an app for my church and I will be using JSON files to store some data like events, list of audio files, lest of personnel, etc.

For my testing, I'm hosting the files on a simple folder in our hosting server, something like www.churchwebhost.com/jsonfiles.

There's no private information on those files and I was thinking on keeping like that for the final release.

So the question is.. Is there a restriction to where you host you JSON files ? I'm just concerned to have the app declined if I do it like that.

Pretty much, I'm looking for best practices for this situation.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe Apple cares where your data is coming from, as long that your app does not crash if the data cannot be reached.

Comment: as for me ill use a database to save that data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction from Apple on where you load data from. You can pull it off a public web site, they will not reject you for that.

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no restriction on where you fetch your data from as it wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Put your files wherever you feel is best, make sure your app handles any situation where it can't access them (no internet connection, airplane mode etc) and you are good to go! Apple don't expect you to put your content in a specific location.